# ruby on rails - parsing url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-services

I've a problem with receive data in controller. I must receive params in web service controller but I have follow problem with that.I researched and found that problem in rails parse this is article about that  [article](http://codefol.io/posts/How-Does-Rack-Parse-Query-Params-With-parse-nested-query) .I would like find some way for parse it myself.I just want take last same item of ulr for example job_name=*. 
I have not receive any data in controller after this error. this is request request and error.

---

> localhost:3000/ws/job_histories/index?job_name=name&job_name[]=*
>
> Status: 500 Internal Server Error
>
> undefined method `each_pair' for nil:NilClass
>
>   org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:238:in`method_missing'
>   C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:52:in
>   `method_missing'
>
>   C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/indifferent_access.rb:46:in`
>   update'
>   C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/indifferent_access.rb:91:in
>   `merge'
>
>   C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/request.rb:385:in`
>   parameters'
>   C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1290:in `assign_shortcuts'
>
>   C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/base.rb:527:in`
>   process'
>   C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:606:in
>   `process_with_filters'
>
>   C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:65:in`call_with_exception'
>   C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:90:in
>   `dispatch'
>
>   C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:87:in`
>   dispatch'
>   C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:85:in
>   `dispatch'
>
>   C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:121:in`
>   _call'
>   C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:130:in
>   `build_middleware_stack'    org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in`call'
>   org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
>
>   C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/string_coercion.rb:25:in`
>   call'
>   C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/gems/rack-1.1.3/lib/rack/head.rb:9:in
>   `call'
>
>   C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/gems/rack-1.1.3/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in`
>   call'
>   C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in
>   `call'
>
>   C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/session/abstract_store.rb:177:in`
>   call'
>   C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in
>   `call'
>
>   C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:34:in`
>   cache'
>   C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:9:in
>   `cache'
>
>   C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:28:in`
>   call'
>   C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:361:in
>   `call'
>
>   C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in`
>   call'
>   C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/gems/rack-1.1.3/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in
>   `call'
>
>   C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/gems/rack-1.1.3/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in`
>   call'
>   C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:114:in
>   `call'
>
>   C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/reloader.rb:34:in`
>   run'
>   C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:108:in
>   `call'
>
>   C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/rack/static.rb:31:in`call'
>   C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/gems/rack-1.1.3/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:49:in
>   `call'    org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1612:in`each'
>   C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/gems/rack-1.1.3/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:41:in
>   `call'
>
>   C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in`
>   call'
>   C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/gems/rack-1.1.3/lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in
>   `call'
>
>   C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/gems/rack-1.1.3/lib/rack/chunked.rb:15:in`
>   call'
>   C:/skybot/int_3_6/skybot-2.0/gui/vendor/gems/rack-1.1.3/lib/rack/handler/mongrel.rb:67:in
>   `process'
>
>   C:/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-java/lib/mongrel.rb:159:in`
>   process_client'    org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1612:in `each'
>
>   C:/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-java/lib/mongrel.rb:158:in`
>   process_client'
>   C:/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-java/lib/mongrel.rb:110:in
>   `process_client'
>
>   C:/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-java/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in`
>   run'    org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
>
>   org/jruby/RubyProc.java:224:in`call'

Comment: I think it would help if you posted your index action

Comment: This is rails error .I've not receive any data in my controllers.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to write a comment, but it will be clearer here:

```
undefined method each_pair' for nil:NilClass
```

This error means you're calling a method / function on a data object which doesn't exist. Considering you're trying to call data from an endpoint, you need to show us the `index` action you're using

```
localhost:3000/ws/job_histories/index?job_name[]=name
```

This should set: `params[:job_name]` which you'll be able to access from your controller action